# Vim character that refuses to paint to Normal color

Tags: vim

I have pointed to it in this image. I can't seem to figure out why it's there.

Vim 7.4 
Running in Tmux, but appears even outside of Tmux

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess: Vim does not paint the last character because that may cause the entire screen to scroll up, as the cursor automatically moves to the following insert position, which would be a new line.

I'm no expert on terminal stuff, for a authoritative answer you may want to reach out to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).

Comment: Pretty good theory. If it's an intentional black by Vim then it won't bother me so much, but if it's something wrong with my settings it's going to drive me nuts :)